# NPM Font Awesome 5

Tags: node.js, npm, fontawesome

В [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40fortawesome%2Ffree-) есть пакеты:

- @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
- @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
- @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
- @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
- @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

Согласно [документации](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/getting-started) ***free-**** дополняют ***fontawesome-svg-core***
Но не ясно включает ли ***fontawesome-free*** в себя все остальные или это что-то отдельное.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free

Comment: Спасибо, я читал описание пакета, но увы я не понял что значит "*I came here to chew bubblegum and install Font Awesome 5 - and I'm all out of bubblegum*" - это какая-то шутка, или речь идет о том что это сборка всех Free или каких-то ещё компонентов...

Comment: наверное имеется в виду, что можно расслабиться и установить пакет, так как больше ничего не нужно делать

Comment: его как раз тут https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css и рекомендуют

Comment: Благодарю, за разъяснение